# more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

Estoy compilando un proyecto de android que fue hecho con kotlin y Java, pero me aparece el siguiente error:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/tools/idea/gradle/run/OutputBuildAction has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
```

Revisé lo que podría estár causando el problema, revise el JDK de mi equipo: [image: Mi jdk instalado]

y Revisé el JDK con el que está trabajando Android Studio:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la configuración Gradle que viene en el proyecto: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hoy en la mañana no me aparecía ese problema, después de que actualicé el Android Studio y actualicé el gradle por medio de una notificación dentro del IDE fue que empezó a aparecer dicho error. Ya intenté resolverlo pero aún no lo logro ¿me podrían ayudar?

Comment: Ahí estás mostrando la configuración de android studio, pero no la del proyecto como tal, que debe estar esperando JDK 11

Comment: ¿Esa información está en File/ProjectEstructure/Project?

Comment: Es correcto. Ese valor de project SDK es el que usa tu proyecto. Y en esa ventana, platform settings --> SDK, revisas que esté disponible el que esperas usar.

Comment: Acabo de revisar el proyecto marca Android gradle plugin version: 3.3.2 y Gradle version: 4.10.1

Answer (score 4):

El error indica:

> ha sido compilado por una versión más reciente de Java Runtime
> (archivo de clase versión 55.0), esta versión de Java Runtime solo
> reconoce versiones de archivos de clase hasta 52.0

Estas son las versiones de Java:

```
45 = Java 1.1
46 = Java 1.2
47 = Java 1.3
48 = Java 1.4
49 = Java 5
50 = Java 6
51 = Java 7
52 = Java 8
53 = Java 9
54 = Java 10
55 = Java 11
56 = Java 12
57 = Java 13
```

El error indica que debes usar Java 11 (55), esto seguramente por la versión de Gradle que usas y que es soportada por Android Studio. Realiza el siguiente cambio en tu proyecto, ve a `File` > `Project Structure...` > `SDK Location`, selecciona la siguiente opción:

[image: jorgesys java android studio]

Después seleciona Android 11, si no lo tienes instalado asegura realizar su instalación.

[image: jorgesys java android studio 2]

Comment: Probé esta solución usando Android Studio Dolphin 2021.3.1 y cuando se quiere ejecutar de nuevo la aplicación marca el siguiente error: `Unable to delete file: path\to\my\app\build\intermediates\signing_config\debug\out\signing-config.json`  Y no, no es posible eliminar el archivo `signing-config.json` en Windows y mucho menos funciona ejecutando Android Studio como administrador. ¿Sabes si hay alguna otra solución? Saludos.

Comment: Eso es otro erro diferente, deberías poder eliminar este archivo usando una cuenta de administrador, te sugiero primeramente ir a File > Invalidate Caches... Si esto no funciona, reinicia tu pc, y sin abrir android studio elimina el directorio path\to\my\app\build\ @FernandoTorres

Comment: Gracias @jorgesys Me sirvió entrar como administrador en Windows y eliminar manualmente ese archivo, luego de eso, todo funcionó bien.

Comment: @FernandoTorres excelente! Saludos.